# How does the earth do a negative work on a static body?

Tags: classical-mechanics, gravity, forces, earth

If a body is in rest and the earth acts with a force on it 10 N

Is there a negative work done by the earth though the body doesn't move? how?

does it have a common thing with potential energy?

Comment: If the body doesn't move then no work is done.

Comment: Why do you think the Earth doesn't move? It doesn't move relative to what?

Comment: @JoshuaLin The OP is talking about the relative distance between the earth and the object.

Comment: No, the Earth does not do work on a body that is at rest relative to the Earth.

Comment: @JoshuaLin I meant the body by "it"

Comment: Is there a negative work? and does have a common thing with potential energy?

Answer (score 2):

By definition, work is
$$W[\gamma] = \int_\gamma\mathbf F\cdot\mathbf v\text dt$$
i.e. force times displacement. If an object is not moving, even if subjected to a force, then there is no work done by said force. Observe that, since the object is not moving, the sum of *all* the forces applied to a body must be zero. For example, a body on rest on a table is subjected to gravity, but also the vincular reaction of the table, which is equal in magnitude, but opposite in direction, to the weight of the body.

Answer (score 0):

Work= force x displacement 
force is weight and displacement is 0 so there is no work (in physics)

Comment: We answered the same time!!!Daahhh

Comment: Wow, even down to the second. I retract my question